# Cómo rellenar una tabla con structs de un mismo tipo en C

Tags: array, c, struct

El problema es el siguiente: tengo un struct congresista de la siguiente forma: (cada vot es el voto que realiza cada congresista en las votaciones de 1 a 16 y partido es el partido al que pertenece cada congresista)

```
typedef struct Congresista{
     
  int vot1;
  int vot2;
  int vot3;  
  int vot4;
  int vot5;
  int vot6;
  int vot7;
  int vot8;   
  int vot9;
  int vot10;        
  int vot11;
  int vot12;
  int vot13;      
  int vot14;
  int vot15;
  int vot16;
  int partido;

}congresista;
```

Ahora quiero introducir 400 congresistas en un array de congresistas a partir de una función que lee dichos congresistas de un archivo csv

```
void readCsv(char c[], congresista congress[]){
    /* Abrimos el fichero del que nos pasan el nombre por fichero */
    FILE *fichero = fopen(c,"r");
    char cadena[385];
    /* Leemos la primera línea que es la de los Atributos */
    fgets(cadena,385,fichero);
    int i = 0;
    
    char *token;
    /* Vamos leyendo cada línea del fichero, vamos creando los congresistas que se almacenan en el array de congresistas*/
    while(fgets(cadena,385,fichero)!=NULL){
        
        congresista cong;
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot1 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot2 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot3 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot4 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot5 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot6 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot7 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot8 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot9 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot10 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot11 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot12 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot13 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot14 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot15 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot16 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        if(strcmp(token,"democrat") == 0){
            cong.partido = 1;
        }
        else if(strcmp(token,"republican") == 0){
            cong.partido = 0;
        }
        
        
        congress[i] = cong;
        i++;
        
    }
    

}
```

El problema que tengo es que creo que estoy rellenando mal el array porque si por ejemplo accedo a la posición congress[0].vot1 me devuelve un 0 cuando debería ser un 1. Sin embargo si hago printf("%d",cong.vot1) sale el resultado correcto ¿Alguien que sepa como solucionar esto?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría usar

```
while (fscanf(fichero, %s, cadena) != NULL)
{
 ...;
}
```

Para verificar si fgets está levantando bien los datos

Y para los votos del congresista puedes usar un arreglo

```
#define N_VOTOS 16

typedef struct Congresista{
     
  int vot[N_VOTOS];
  int partido;

}congresista;
```

No he usado mucho esa función srtok, aunque según el código no parece que estés avanzando sobre la línea cargada en cadena. Podrías implementar la obtención del campo
de cada línea del csv con un while:

```
// Función que lee una cadena (una línea del CSV) y devuelve un congresista con sus votos

congresista leer_votos(char* cadena)
{
  char car_leido = '\0';
  char* token;
  int i = 0;  // contador para caracteres de cadena
  int j = 0;  // contador para caracteres de tokens
  int vot_i = 0   // indice de votos

  congresista cong_aux; // Congresista Auxiliar

  for (i = 0, vot_i = 0; (i < strlen(cadena) + 1) && (vot_i < N_VOTOS); i++) {
    
    while ((car_leido = cadena[i]) != ',') {
      
       token[j] = car_leido;
       j++;
    }

    j = 0; // Reiniciar para próximo token

    cong_aux.vot[vot_i++] = atoi(token); // Guardar e incrementar vot_i

    strcpy(token, ""); // borrar token
  }
  
  return cong_aux;
}
```

Es una idea, espero que te sea útil. Saludos!