# Cómo rellenar una tabla con structs en C

Tags: array, c, struct, tokens

El problema es el siguiente: tengo un struct congresista de la siguiente forma: (cada vot es el voto que realiza cada congresista en las votaciones de 1 a 16 y partido es el partido al que pertenece cada congresista)

```
typedef struct Congresista{
     
  int vot1;
  int vot2;
  int vot3;  
  int vot4;
  int vot5;
  int vot6;
  int vot7;
  int vot8;   
  int vot9;
  int vot10;        
  int vot11;
  int vot12;
  int vot13;      
  int vot14;
  int vot15;
  int vot16;
  int partido;

}congresista;
```

Ahora quiero introducir 400 congresistas en un array de congresistas a partir de una función que lee dichos congresistas de un archivo csv

```
void readCsv(char c[], congresista congress[]){
    /* Abrimos el fichero del que nos pasan el nombre por fichero */
    FILE *fichero = fopen(c,"r");
    char cadena[385];
    /* Leemos la primera línea que es la de los Atributos */
    fgets(cadena,385,fichero);
    int i = 0;
    
    char *token;
    /* Vamos leyendo cada línea del fichero, vamos creando los congresistas que se almacenan en el array de congresistas*/
    while(fgets(cadena,385,fichero)!=NULL){
        
        congresista cong;
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot1 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot2 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot3 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot4 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot5 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot6 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot7 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot8 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot9 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot10 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot11 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot12 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot13 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot14 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot15 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        cong.vot16 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(cadena, ",");
        if(strcmp(token,"democrat") == 0){
            cong.partido = 1;
        }
        else if(strcmp(token,"republican") == 0){
            cong.partido = 0;
        }
        
        
        congress[i] = cong;
        i++;
        
    }
    

}
```

El problema que tengo es que creo que estoy rellenando mal el array porque si por ejemplo accedo a la posición congress[0].vot1 me devuelve un 0 cuando debería ser un 1. Sin embargo si hago printf("%d",cong.vot1) sale el resultado correcto ¿Alguien que sepa por qué asigna mal al array los elementos de tipo congresista?

Comment: ¿ Para que publicas una nueva pregunta ? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/411914/c%c3%b3mo-rellenar-una-tabla-con-structs-de-un-mismo-tipo-en-c [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/411914/edit) la anterior para añadir detalles, deja mensajes al usuario que te contestó si su respuesta no es correcta. Como último recurso, elimina la anterior.

Comment: Y creando usuarios nuevos pierdes la reputación anterior. Si has perdido las credenciales y no puedes acceder, ponte en contacto con un moderador. Publicar una pregunta [en meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/) es una forma efectiva de hacerlo.

Comment: A ver Juano, mi problema es que cuando he hecho la primera pregunta no estaba registrado en stackoverflow y por lo tanto ahora no puedo o no sé como acceder a la cuenta con la que habia hecho la preimera pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Perdón, Juanjo*

Comment: Intenta seguir [este procedimiento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) para unir tus dos cuentas en una.

Comment: Ya he hecho eso pero no se si se podrán combinar, la primera cuenta no esta registrada.